# VueJS: Import library using CDN URL instead of NPM

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a **library** built for some apps in my company and now I publish it into NPM and 10 apps are using my library.

These apps import my library using:

```
import * as mylib from 'mylib-kit'
Vue.use(mylib)
```

But every time I update my library, this apps have to run command `npm update` and it seems not convenient. So I deploy it in a CDN URL:

`https://cdn.mylib.vn/mylib.umd.js`

How can these apps can import my library using this CDN URL instead `npm`?

Answer (score 0):

if your browsers suport, you can do this.check for [suport](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)

or you can use plugins do it (like [browserify-cdnjs](https://github.com/dsdenes/browserify-cdnjs)、[scriptjs](https://github.com/ded/script.js) .etc)

thanks.